# how to use one variable second time in different view function in django

Tags: python, django

Let me give a example.My views.py is like this.

```
def view1(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    #gather form put in a list
    li=[form_value1,form_value2]
    #do something with li
    return HttpResponse()# Have to use HttpResponse
    # in that there is a link of view2 
 return render(request,'form.html',{})
def view2(request):
  #here i want to use li again
```

Can I declear it as global

```
def view1(request):
  global li
  li=[form_value1,form_value2]
```

or can I use like this

```
li = []
def view1(request):
  li.append(form_value1)
def view2(request):
  #extract li
```

In both case I got unsuccessful
So please guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are those `form_value`s? If you're getting them inside the view method how do you expect they'll be available globally?

Comment: They are simple integer. So what can be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are the easiest way to achieve this:

```
def view1(request):

    if request.POST: 
        request.session['li'] = [form_value1,form_value2]
        return HttpResponse()

    return render(request,'form.html',{})

def view2(request):

    li = request.session['li']

    ...
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: I am Little bit new to web devlopment. So m I have to add anything in seting .py. I am using django 1.6. I have not active session. So only that much will work? I have not changed anything from default

Comment: You just need to make sure you have `django.contrib.sessions` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py

Comment: Can I declear & assign li 1st,
Then do session `request.session['li']`

Comment: Yes. In view1 `li = [form_value1,form_value2]` then `request.session['li'] = li` then in view2 `li = request.session['li']`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the value back in the response to the client and then back again to the server when they request page 2. That could be done via cookies, hidden form fields, embedded in Javascript or a number of other options.

There are ways around this but all of them require your server being stateful.

The next best option is the concept of a session. This is a per-user storage space with a limited lifetime (usually extended to -say- 20 minutes every time a request comes in from that user). You could store user-specific variables there. This mitigates the threading issues and limits the wasted server resources. A client is given a unique id (usually in a cookie) which is used to look up their session data on the server. See [Django Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) for more information.

If you made a variable global, it would apply to all users of your site and would be accessed from multiple threads (which means you need to understand about all the usual threading problems like race conditions).

Comment: Thank You for your answer.
The thing is how can I send that data(may be hidden input) with httpresponse

Comment: @Swagat You're welcome. I just added a little bit about sessions which may be the compromise you need

Answer (score 0):

li will be recreated for each request as is the nature of web servers which are stateless. Each view handles a request and so li will not be available to the next. You could use memcached to store the value of li and retrieve it in the other view or you could look at sessions.

Comment: I don't _believe_ this is true for Django as each module is loaded only once (on startup) then the methods are called on demand. So technically module-level code outside of methods should be server-wide, but I agree it's not the right way to do things and doesn't translate to other servers

Comment: Your right. Have a look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/c2ZwrzP_0gs.